# What is a phobia against babies or kids called?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, terminology, phobia

I have heard about people that experience fears for other people, or groups of people; for example a fear for babies.

- Is this a recognized pathologocal condition, or is it just a form of antisocial behavior; or maybe a sort of fear for the unknown, such as [new fathers fearing their newborn](https://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2013/12/why-men-fear-small-babies/282616/)?

Answer (score 6):

A rather cursory search brought me to [the wikipedia page for fear of children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_of_children):

- ***[Pedophobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_of_children)***:

> [The] fear of children, fear of infants or fear of childhood [..].

This as opposed to a pathological love for children, or [pedophilia](https://www.psychologytoday.com/conditions/pedophilia), which as an ongoing sexual attraction to pre-pubertal children.

In case it is a fear specifically for infants, there is a more narrowly scoped type of phobia defined, namely:

- **[Brephophobia](http://phobia.wikia.com/wiki/Brephophobia)**, or **infantophobia** :

> [T]he fear of infant. It is more commonly suffered by adults,
>   especially fertilizable women. The fear is commonly triggered due to
>   miscarriage, and pressures on caring for baby.

Answer (score 1):

This specific phobia doesn't exist, but I think that the symptom you described could be part of a **Social Anxiety Disorder (Social Phobia)**

According to DSM-5,  a criterion for the diagnosis is: "Marked fear or anxiety about *one* or more social situations in which the individual is exposed to possible scrutiny by others. Examples include social interactions (e.g., having a conversation, meeting unfamiliar people), being observed (e.g., eating or drinking), and performing in front of others (e.g., giving a speech)."

**REFERENCES**
DSM - 5 (2013)